# How to add a qresource under another one in a QRC file

Tags: c++, xml, qt

I'm developing a C++ program with **Qt** 4.5 and I'd like to configure my resource file (**.qrc**) with several resource path. To do so I'd like to add some **subpath**, but it seems it does not work if I try to add a  under another one. Does anybody knows if **this is possible?** I didn't see anything about this in [the doc](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/resources.html).

For example, here is what I tried:

```
<RCC>
  <qresource prefix="/path1">
    <qresource prefix="subpath1">
      <file alias="file1">...</file>
    </qresource>
    <qresource prefix="subpath2">
      <file alias="file2">...</file>
    </qresource>
  </qresource>
</RCC>
```

Then trying to access it this way does not work (object is empty):

```
QImage(":/path1/subpath1/file1")
```

Note that I already tried to change the qrc file with "/subpath1" instead of "subpath1" without any effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Paths in Qt resource files are artificial constructs, therefore you need to explicitly define your path structure by hand (as opposed to xml structure):

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/path1"/>
    <qresource prefix="/path2">
        <file>style.css</file>
    </qresource>
    <qresource prefix="/path1/subpath">
        <file>substyle.css</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

Comment: Thanks, I expected something like this but wanted some confirmation.